# removing the battery of my hp pavillion g6 while gaming

Tags: battery

hey i wanted to know that is it safe for remove the battery of my laptop and use it by plugging in the charger when i am playing games like COD or NFS. will the battery or the laptop be affected in any ways. Does Hp reccomend that? plus the battery of my laptop is very bad it give like 3-4 hours of normal usage of the laptop when on lowest brightness.

Comment: Yes, you can remove it if pluged in.. why would you want to though?

Comment: If the DC power is plugged in the removing the battery would only prevent it from charging.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop is plugged in it wont affect anything since it isn't using your battery in anyway except to charge it.. hope this helps!